# Receive int in RootviewController creation method

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, int

I have this RootViewController creation method, i want receive int value but i don't know how.

```
 + (RootViewController2*) loadNames:(NSArray*)names sec:(int)sec
    {
        RootViewController2 * cont2 = [[RootViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController2" bundle:nil];

        [cont2 set???????:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sec]];
        [cont2 setSubsecciones:names];
        return [cont2 autorelease];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you add a `sec` int assign property and use `[cont2 setSec:sec]`?

Example:

In you `RootViewController2` class interface add:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) int sec;
```

In your `RootViewController2` class implementation add:

```
@synthesize sec;
```

And then in `loadNames` use:

```
cont2.sec = sec;
```

Or if you don't like the property dot-notation:

```
[cont2 setSec:sec];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[cont2 setSomeSelector:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sec]];
```

Are you added some Selector in RootViewController2?

I don't understand you're core problem.

Comment: The problem is that don't find any selecter that return NSNumber.

Comment: I don't understand you're problem. Would you more detail explain to me?

Comment: "setSomeSelector:", this selector is the definition name in .h file.

Comment: In my header file, i have this definition:                            + (RootViewController2*) loadNames:(NSArray*)names numS:(int)numSec;   But i don't find any selector with this name.